# What type of object is this?

Tags: android, view, widget

I have seen this in several apps, and I was wondering if this is in the API.  It basically looks like a speech bubble but it allows for internal layouts within it.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a custom view... you can implement something like that easily or use this code:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions

By the way, in order to create a correct bubble you must use a 9patch image.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)